# How to change Team for git repository in Team Services

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

We recently started using Git on Team Services after using TFVC for several years. I'm succesfully connected to a Team Services repository, but the work items I'm getting are for the wrong team (see attached picture).

The git url for my repository already contains a specific team (the wrong one obviously) so how can I change that information?

[image: Team Explorer]

Comment: Do you mean a Team Project? Teams and Team Projects are not the same thing.

Comment: No I meant actual teams inside a Team Project

Answer (score 0):

It’s unnecessary to change teams is VS. And it only shows the default team in visual studio team explorer.

When you create a git repo in VSTS, it will shared with all the teams in the same project. So no matter which team you connected in VS, the pushed changes will be used for all the teams.

Besides, you can find it in git repo URL (code Tab and clone button is VSTS) like https://account.visualstudio.com/_git/project or https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/repo, it’s not related to teams.

Comment: My question was specific to work items and which are shown for the product backlog query. I know repos are available across all teams, but I found the solution to my question.

Comment: It is also related to visible Pull Requests and other features, so it is indeed a valid question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. In VS 2017 after connecting to a git repo through Team Services you can select a team if you're member of more than one.

So Home/Team Spezialentwicklung is actually a button which allows you to select your team under "Projects and My Teams"

[image: Screenshot]